# How to test a custom route [ActionController::RoutingError:]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller

test output:

```
Failures:

  1) AccountsController account signs up  
     Failure/Error: post :create, account_id: account.id
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:account_id=>"1", :controller=>"accounts", :action=>"create"}
     # ./spec/controllers/accounts_controller_spec.rb:24:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

routes.rb:

```
post 'sign_up', to: 'accounts#create'
```

spec:

```
RSpec.describe AccountsController, type: :controller do
...
it '' do
  post :create, account_id: account.id
  ...
end
```

I have a custom route that points to my create method. I want to not care about the route. I have a route test that works. Now I want to test the logic in the create method.

How do I test the `create` method with a custom route?

I tried doing `post 'my_custom_route'` and that did not work.

Rails: 3.2

Rspec: 3

Edit: I just used `account.id` as an example. It's not a real parameter in my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `:id`, not `:account_id`

```
post :create, id: account.id
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I test the create method with a custom route?

You can't, at least not in a controller spec.

Unit tests for controllers are intended to test the body of the action(s), not the routes. So you always need to specify the action—the dispatcher is not resolving routes for you in this case.

You can write a [routing spec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#routing-specs) to verify that the custom route works as expected. Or you can write a [feature spec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#routing-specs) that hits the desired URL.

Comment: I think we are in agreement. I want to test the #create action. I do not really care about the custom route (I do not want to care about the routes.rb file at all). Any idea why my `post :create` would not work?

Comment: `No route matches` generally means you have specified the parameters correctly. What does `rake routes` say?